# web service problem in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.8

i have a problem with netbeans IDE.

i created a web project , i can run it by index.jsp. it`s deploy and running successfully
but when i create webService in that, the project can deploy but not running
and web service dont run .

when i test web service, i see this warning:

```
  Unable to open web service tester page:
  http://localhost:8084/sample4/TestWebService
  Make sure the service has been deployed successfully, and the server is running.
```

netbeans version is 6.8

tomcat 6.0

jdk 1.6

Can somebody please advice on this issue?

Comment: please, if you have solved this, post the solution because I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I have same problem!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, quite an obscure problem:

Project A is a Web project with dependency on project B, which depends on project C. Project C is the web service client generated with wsimport from the WSDL generated by project A (somehow a clean cycle).

My problem arised at the very moment when I rearranged the order of the libraries of project B, placing project C as the first of the list in the classpath (don't know if this matters, but before the call to catalina.jar).

So, when I rearranged my libraries in project B, placing the reference to project C as second of the list, everything went back to normal.

Wether if this works or not, please comment.